# Edit a Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to edit a google spreadsheet using google apps script. Basically, I have a cell in the spreadsheet that has the value "Pending Approval" in it. When the script is executed, I want it to change the value in that cell to "Approved". Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.getRange** and **.setValue** are the methods you will want to use in whatever you are trying to do.  This little function will just take the cell notation as the first argument, and then the value you want to set as the second.

```
function setCellValue(cellName, value) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange(cellName);
  cell.setValue(value);

}

setCellValue("A1","Approved");
```